# deleted function, can't rewrite one record to another, objects

Tags: c++, class, object

I'm new here so sorry if I do something wrong.

I make a school project. In function I can't simply use

```
tab[i] = tab[i + 1];
```

It shows error:
*an element of a function "Pilkarz::operator=(const Pilkarz&)" (is declared implicitly) cannot be referenced - this is a removed function*

This is my first class:

```
class Player
{
protected:
string Name;
string SName;
string Position;
int Age;
float AvGoals;
int los;
fstream plik;
string poz[7] = { "Napastnik", "Skrzydlowy", "Obronca", "Napastnik", "Pomocnik", "Bramkarz", "Boczny Obronca" };
};

public:
Player(string="Imie", string="Nazwisko", string="Pozycja", int=0, float=0, float=1);
};
```

This is my second class:

```
class Club:public Player
{
protected:
Player* tab;
int counter, current, size;
fstream plik2;

private:
int i;
int skrzydlowy = 0, pomocnik = 0, bObronca = 0, bramkarz = 0;

public:
Club(int);
};
```

The function I want to make:

```
void Club::deleteCurrent() {
        for (i = current; i < size - 1; i++)
        {
            tab[i] = tab[i + 1];
        }
}
```

The problem is that I can't use this: tab[i] = tab[i +1];
I have to use setters and getters to make it work. What's the problem?
I work with Visual Studio Enterprise 2019.

Comment: `fstream plik;` -- This member cannot be copied.  Streams cannot be copied

Comment: "Every player has a file" and "a club is a kind of player that isn't just a player but also has a collection of players and yet another file" seem pretty odd.

Comment: @molbdnilo you mean it's bad that every Player object has his own file? Class Player shouldn't have fstream member?

Comment: @l1ght It's not necessarily *bad*, but that depends on what it's for. Even if you have a "one file per object" structure, file I/O is usually (and more conveniently) handled outside the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The member `fstream plik;` is not copyable. It has a deleted copy constructor: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream

Therefore the compiler can't generate the default copy assignment operator. You can either remove `fstream plik;` from your class or add a user-defined copy assignment operator:

```
Pilkarz &operator=(const Pilkarz &p) {
    /* copy all members */
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Is there other solution? I need fstream to make my other function work. When I do
`tab[i] = tab[i+1];`
It copies all elements from Class? Even functions?

Comment: @l1ght No, you can't copy an object of type `fstream`. You have to specify the behavior of a copy for this member. But probably this shouldn't be a member of this class in the first place. Member functions are not copied. They belong to the class and not to the object.

Comment: The good practice is to pass things like input/output strems (`fstream`) to the function using them as a parameter.
For example you want to print your `Player` to some file, you rather add `Player::Print(ostream& plik);` instead of storing some `fstream` in the `Player` objects and having `Player::Print()`

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasSablik now I understand.
@seb why `Print(ostream& plik);` and not just `Print(fstream plik);` ?

Comment: @l1ght -- What if I want to print to any type of stream, not just a file stream?  For example: `std::ostringstream strm;  Print(strm);` will send the output to the string stream if the type is `ostream&`.

Answer (score 1):

implicitly declared assignment operator is deleted because one of the members of `class Pilkarz` has deleted the assignment operator

sample code:
https://godbolt.org/z/eGosWc

You can see that the `fstream flk;` member has deleted its implicit copy assignment operator.

```
<source>:15:9: note: copy assignment operator of 'Pilkarz' is implicitly deleted because field 'plik' has a deleted copy assignment operator
fstream plik;
```

You need to override the default implementation of `class Pilkarz` copy assignment operator with explicit implementation which only copies members who are allowed to copy.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. But how can I define which parameters can be copied?